# Select random '1' element from a logical matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

So what I am trying to do is simply select random '1' element from logical matrix in matlab. 
Suppose I have a matrix like this:

```
 A= 0 1 1 1 0
    0 1 0 1 1
    1 0 0 0 0
    0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0
```

and I have a number **n** which is a number that represent how many '1' elements will be selected in the procedure

For example if `n=3` then the output can be looks like this:

```
 A'= 0 1 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 1
     0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 1 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0
```

***note that the maximum value possible for n is the number of '1' elements in matrix being processed**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should find the indexes of the 1s, choose n unique random integers, and handle those indexes:

```
n = 3;
A= [0 1 1 1 0;
    0 1 0 1 1;
    1 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 1 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0];

% // idx of the ones in the matrix, also has information on size
idx = find(A == 1);

% // n unique rand numbers from 1 till nr_of_ones
randidx = randperm(numel(idx), n);

% // new matrix 
B = zeros(size(A));

% // select the random indexes
B(idx(randidx)) = 1
```